# Devise reset password link not working but works when the "www" is clipped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My question is similar but the opposite of this one:

[Devise password reset link not working with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370289/devise-password-reset-link-not-working-with-https)

My devise password reset link is not working. The link brings me to

https://www.thesofiaproject.ai/members/password/edit?reset_password_token=XXXXXX

But this works

https://thesofiaproject.ai/members/password/edit?reset_password_token=XXXXXX

i.e, remove the www. and it works.

Here is my production.rb in relation to email

```
    ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 's.walsh@XXXXXX.XX.XX'

    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    host = 'https://XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX.herokuapp.com'

    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'https' }

    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
         :user_name => 'apikey'
         :password => XXXX, 
         :domain => 'www.thesofiaproject.ai',
         :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
         :port => 587,
         :authentication => :plain,
         :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` is just used to configure the SMTP connection and has nothing to do with how your views generate links. If I had to guess why this isn't working as intended I would guess that your config is a bit of a mess and you're contradicting yourself . For example by setting the host in config/application.rb. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views

Answer (score 0):

To have the link in the email without the www you need to remove it from the host variable:

```
host = 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX.herokuapp.com'
```

Comment: I thought this, but it doesn't make a difference. The www. is still prepended.

Comment: @GhostRider you are right, my bad. Can you try to remove the `'https://` from the host?
 host = 'XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX.herokuapp.com'

Comment: ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings is just used to configure the SMTP connection and has nothing to do with how your views generate links.